ImportHTML won't import commented out tables on Google Sheets
I've been attempting to collect football data on FBref using Google Sheet's ImportHTML function and while it works for the most part, it is having some issues with importing some tables.
I get the error "Imported content does not have query with given index." when attempting to import the third table in this link: "https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/shooting/Championship-Stats" which shows the shooting stats of specific players.
I believe this is due to the table being commented out in the code, but still showing up on the website.
With the table still being there, is there another way I can import this data using the ImportHTML function that I am missing?
I have tried the usual import function, which is =ImportHTML("https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/shooting/Championship-Stats", "table", 3)
While this works for indexes one and two (team stats for and against), this doesn't appear to work for the individual players on index 3.

I believe this is due to the table being commented out in the code, but still showing up on the website. Correct. Comments are represented in HTML and XML as content between ''. In this case the html is bad. Prior to table #3, the first half of the comment (<!--) exists but there is no closing portion for the comment.

you'd have to add a script that will "clean" the html (Ie remove the <!-- and -->, and then get the table at index 3
